# Combine 2 Radiogroups in Android

Tags: android

I have 2 radiogroups. The first with 4 buttons and the second with 3 buttons.
I need a solution to update a timer in a TextView depending on what is checked in both radiogroups. In the first radiogroup the user chooses size and in the second the user chooses shape. That gives 12 combinations. So far I have only figured out how to update the TextView field from 1 radiogroup. In the code below I have shown 2 values from the first radiogroup (rg1). They should change depending on what is chosen in radiogroup 2 (rg2)

I have found a solution and updated the code. Hope it can help others.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    TextView timer;
    RadioGroup rg1;
    RadioGroup rg2;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.softTimer);

        rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup1);
        rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        rg2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup2);
        rg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


    }

 @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        RadioButton s1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.size_small);
        RadioButton s2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.size_medium);
        RadioButton s3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.size_large);
        RadioButton s4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.size_xlarge);
        RadioButton b1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.boil_soft);
        RadioButton b2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.boil_medium);
        RadioButton b3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.boil_hard);

        if (s1.isChecked() && b1.isChecked()){
            tid = 204000;
            eggTimer.setText("00:03:24");
        }
        else if (s1.isChecked() && b2.isChecked()) {
            tid = 255000;
            eggTimer.setText("00:04:15");
        }
        else if (s1.isChecked() && b3.isChecked()) {
            tid = 341000;
            eggTimer.setText("00:05:41");
        }
        else if (s2.isChecked() && b1.isChecked()){
            tid = 239000;
            eggTimer.setText("00:03:59");
        }
        else if (s2.isChecked() && b2.isChecked()) {
            tid = 279000;
            eggTimer.setText("00:04:39");
        }
        else if (s2.isChecked() && b3.isChecked()) {
            tid = 396000;
            eggTimer.setText("00:06:36");
        }
        else if (s3.isChecked() && b1.isChecked()){
            tid = 270000;
            eggTimer.setText("00:04:30");
        }
        else if (s3.isChecked() && b2.isChecked()) {
            tid = 325000;
            eggTimer.setText("00:05:25");
        }
        else if (s3.isChecked() && b3.isChecked()) {
            tid = 485000;
            eggTimer.setText("00:08:05");
        }
        else if (s4.isChecked() && b1.isChecked()){
            tid = 336000;
            eggTimer.setText("00:05:36");
        }
        else if (s4.isChecked() && b2.isChecked()) {
            tid = 400000;
            eggTimer.setText("00:06:40");
        }
        else if (s4.isChecked() && b3.isChecked()) {
            tid = 603000;
            eggTimer.setText("00:10:03");
        }

        final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(tid, 1000);
        tv_start_egg1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                timer.start();
            }
        });

        tv_stop_egg1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                timer.cancel();
                tid = 0;
                eggTimer.setText("00:00:00");

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it. That way the question will be listed as answered. Thank you.

Comment: So I should replace the code with the old one, post a new with the solution and then set that as the answer? Sorry but i am new to this site :-)

Comment: No need to change the question code. I don't think anyone will benefit from the wrong code. The point is that if anyone sees your "Combine 2 Radio groups in android" question, they should find the answer. The only reason to put it in an accepted answer is that other people can see it has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I have updated the code. Hope it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get checked radio button id from radio group 2.

```
int radioButtonID = rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Now handle your conditions accordingly.

Comment: And how do I handle the 2 radiogroups ID's in my switch?

Answer (score 0):

Easily. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    switch(group.getId()) {
        case R.id.myRadioGroup1:
            //We are in the first radio group.
            switch(checkedId) {
                case R.id.size_small:
                    timer.setText("00:04:15");
                    break;
                case R.id.size_large:
                    timer.setText("00:01:15");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.myRadioGroup2:
            //We are in the second radio group. Do as you need.
            break;
    }
}
```

However, I am confused as why you don't just use the `int checkedId` for the second group as well. Each radio button that is checked has a different id for it.

Comment: I have found a solution. The problem with your solution is that timer.setText don't calculate the values in both radiogroup 1 and radiogroup 2. If I check radiogroup 1 in the first button and radiogroup 2 in the first button I get one value that is used in timer.setText. If I change radiogroup2 to button 2 and keep radiogroup checked in button 1, I get a new value for timer.setText. I have updated my code to the solution i found.

Comment: Well, that is a different question than what was asked :) You just wanted to get the second radiogroup clicks which is what I answered. I'm glad you got it resolved!